# Return C++ enum to C# - double free tcache 2 error

Tags: c#, c++, linux, enums, dllimport

I'm trying to pass an `enum` to/from C++ and C#. Both are running on Linux. The program runs and works but upon the program ending I get a `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` error and then a core dump. I've isolated the issue to C++ returning an `enum` to C#, see below. C++ receiving an `enum` from C# appears to work without issue. Linux is running the .NET6 SDK.

C++ Header (.so file):

```
enum class Example : int
{
    Item0 = 0,
    Item1 = 1,
    Item2 = 2
};

extern "C" Example Test(Example ex);
```

C++ Source (.so file):

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    Example Test(Example ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Received enum: " << static_cast<int>(ex) << std::endl;

        return Example::Item2;    // Returning an enum causes the issue, see below.
    }
}
```

C# Code (console app as .dll run by `dotnet` command):

```
[DllImport(DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Test")]
static extern Example Test(Example ex);

Example ex = Test(Example.Item0);
Console.WriteLine("Enum: " + ex.ToString());

enum Example : int
{
    Item0 = 0,
    Item1 = 1,
    Item2 = 2
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
$ dotnet test.dll
Received enum: 0
Enum: Item2
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What works and what I've tried - if I change `Example Test(Example ex)` to `void Test(Example ex)` and remove the `return Example::Item2;` line (while making the equivalent changes in the C# code) then everything works perfectly well. So the issue appears to be only with returning the `enum` from C/C++ to C#. Since these are just `int` values I assume they are copied and no dynamic memory is allocated or freed. What am I missing here?

Comment: @dbc - I see my post was edited to add the 'dllimport' tag. A 'tcache' tag would be better since others will face this error too.

Comment: There is no [tag:tcache] tag.  There is a [tag:dllimport] import tag with 2,270 questions, and a [tag:pinvoke] with 3,747 questions questions.  You are much, much more likely to attract the attention of somebody who can answer your question by using one of those two well-known tags than by introducing a completely unknown tag.   In particular you need somebody who knows about dllimport and platform invocation on .NET on Linux, so I'd strongly recommend having one of both of them.  (And you are in fact using `DllImport` so the tag is applicable.)

Comment: @dbc - I know there isn't a 'tcache' tag, it should be added since it is a known error type. 'dllimport' is fine, but 'tcache' should also be added since people will search for this error. 'tcache' has 239 results with people using 'free' and 'double-free' to try and describe the error. Adding this tag would allow more visibility to the problem.

Comment: Looks like you need [1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to create a tag, so you could post on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/) asking somebody to create it.  I'm not familiar enough with the topic to create it myself.  You are also welcome to remove [tag:dllimport] from your question -- it's your question after all -- but if you do, be aware you will be reducing your chances of getting help from a subject matter expert.  Good luck.

Comment: @dbc - 'dllimport' is useful too, I'm not questioning that. But you could also add 'tcache' given your rep level. Do a search for 'tcache' and see how people are trying to work around tags, 'tcache' is needed. Not having this tag is also limiting my scope from subject matter expert. If I had to choose between either 'tcache' and 'dllimport', I'd say 'tcache' correctly describes the error I'm having because that error may not be related to 'dllimport'.